# Implement a simple search in reactnative

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to implement a simple search in a view.

I have a TextInput component where user can type a search term.

The TextInput is handled by a function which waits 2 seconds then sends the text term to an api.

Here is the api the handler fonction:

```
performSearch(text){
    var typingTimer = null;

    if(typingTimer){
      typingTimer = null;
    }
    typingTimer = setTimeout( () => {
      this.setState({
        search: text
      });
      console.log(this.state.search);
    }, 2000);
  }
```

Here is the behavior I would love to have: if user type something the api call is only made 2 seconds after the user hits the last key. If the user hits another key before 2 seconds, only the last value of the TextInput must be sent.

Unfortunately I can achieve it for now. Any help would be highly appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Why dont you just have a submit button with this text input... I am super confused - is this supposed to be a typeahead or something?

Comment: hi. In fact I have a ListView below the textInput. The goal is to refresh the list according to what is typed inside the textInput without making the user hit a button.

Comment: I think u never go into if condition. Because "typingTimer" variable is null always when u call performSearch() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
performSearch(text){
    clearTimeout(this.typingTimer);// this will cancel the previous timer

    this.typingTimer = setTimeout( () => {
      this.setState({
        search: text
      });
    }, 2000);
  }
```

Comment: Great response. Thanks a lot